# Spring JMS : Set ErrorHandler for @JmsListener annotated method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am using a `@JmsListener` annotated method listen to JMS messages as shown below.

```
@JmsListener(destination="exampleQueue")  
public void fetch(@Payload String message){  
    process(message);  
}
```

When this method execution result in an exception, I got a warn log

```
Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
```

How do I set an `ErrorHandler` to handle the case. I am using spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922532/execution-of-jms-message-listener-failed-and-no-errorhandler-has-been-set

Comment: Thanks @sarahTheButterFly. Got solution by referring Kuchi answer in the link provided. I have tuned the answer a bit to work in my case. I am posting my answer below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While using annotations like `@EnableJms`, `@JmsListener` etc to work with Spring JMS, the ErrorHandler can be set like this

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExampleErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
}

@Service
public class ExampleErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{   
    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        //handle exception here
    }
}
```

More details are available here : [Annotation-driven listener endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated)