# how can i read messages from IBM MQ using spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I have configured the connection to IBM MQ using application properties. As below,

```
ibm.mq.conn-name=localhost(1415)
ibm.mq.queue-manager=QMGR
ibm.mq.channel=QMGR.SVR.CON.C
ibm.mq.user=xxxxx
ibm.mq.password=xxxxx
```

I have class annotated @service which has method as below that reads messages from queue,

```
@Service
public class JMSService {
@Inject
private JmsTemplate queueTemplate;

public JmsMessageBean readMessage(String responseQueueName, Logger logger) throws JMSException, Exception {
        JmsMessageBean bean = new JmsMessageBean();
        MQQueue queue = new MQQueue(responseQueueName);
        queue.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
        queueTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsTemplate.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT);
        Message message = queueTemplate.receive(queue);
        if(message!=null){
            String jmsCorrelationID = hexStringToByteArrayToString(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
            bean.setJmsCorrelationID(jmsCorrelationID);
            bean.setMessage(message.getBody(Object.class));
            bean.setJmsMessageID(message.getJMSMessageID());
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

and i m running a scheduler at fixedRate of 50milliseconds and calling above method in the scheduler,

```
@Component
public class QueueConnectionService{
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 50)
    public void connectQueueManager() {
        JmsMessageBean bean = null;
        int umacIndex;
        String body = "";
        try {
            bean = jmsService.readMessage(env.getProperty("inwardQueueName"), inwardqueue);

            if (bean != null && bean.getMessage() != null) {

                String messagetxt = "";
                if (bean.getMessage().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("String")) {
                    messagetxt = (String) bean.getMessage();
                } else {
                    byte[] messagebytes = (byte[]) bean.getMessage();
                    messagetxt = new String(messagebytes);
                }
                umacIndex = messagetxt.indexOf("{UMAC:");
                if (umacIndex > 0)
                    message = messagetxt.substring(0, umacIndex);
                else
                    message = messagetxt;
                //sending this message to further processing
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

This is working but I m sure this is not the right and efficient way to read messages from queue and probably wrong implementation when there can be large amount messages. And the spring TaskSchedulerPool will be overloaded as there are other data migration schedulers. Please verify and suggest me efficient methods in reading messages from IBM MQ. thank you.

Comment: Use a message listener

Comment: @JoshMc can you please share an example on how to configure and read messages from mq? thank u

Comment: Does this apply: https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS

Comment: @JoshMc as it is a blocking queue i thought it should not wait there if there are no messages on the queue

Comment: @JoshMc above github link that u shared doesn't look to help me out. Thanks for your effort ....is there any other simple example?

Comment: Any reason for the `RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT`?

Comment: @JoshMc regarding RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT, as it is a blocking queue i thought it should not wait there if there are no messages on the queue

Comment: Wait is how long to wait in ms before returning 2033, you still get the message as soon as one is present on the queue.

Comment: @JoshMc ok...on the other hand do u think using scheduler is not the right to read messages from queue? It would be lot helpful if u can share some sample message listener code

Comment: Maybe this: https://marketaylor.synology.me/?p=668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoshMc suggested, you should use a `JmsListener`.

There is good [JMS Getting Started Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) from Spring. For you it will look like this (definition for `myFactory` you can see in the mentioned Spring guide):

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

  @JmsListener(destination = "${inwardQueueName}", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(javax.jms.Message message) throws javax.jms.JMSException {
    String messagetxt = "";
    if (message instanceof javax.jms.TextMessage) {
      messagetxt = message.getBody(String.class);
    }
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: so when the application starts it will connect to the queue and wait for the messages to arrive in the queue and read them? There will be no need of scheduler here to invoke read method right? I will try and implement this way and hope that program control doesn't wait until there's messages in the queue.

Comment: Yes and yes. It is a simple as that :-)

Comment: Hello @Daniel...this solution is working..i will post the code...Thank you so much for this. I would like to know if the listener has any time interval while reading messages? If yes how can we reduce it? and what are the major things or exceptions that can occur using this process which i should be seriously concerned about?

Comment: See the link to the last blog I posted above, if you are have `consumerType` set to `Default` or not set at all, it polls the queue by doing a connect/open/get/close/disconnect every 1 seconds which is bad.  Changing the timeout to 30 seconds or more in the default is better, this does not mean a message will take 30 seconds to get to you, it just means that your app will only connect to MQ every 30 seconds minimum.  Better yet don't use the `Default`, instead use "Simple", this will use the call back feature instead where the MQ QMGR notifies the listener immediately.

Comment: @JoshMc refering to the above link you shared i have updated my spring boot version to 2.0.0 and set spring.jms.listener.receive-timeout=30s in properties file. Will that be enough to solve the speed of reading messages?

Comment: @AkshayGundawar: Receive timeout of 30 seconds for the blocking read on the queue is a good default. You will receive the message immediately. One big benefit of this timeout is to allow a clean shutdown of the Spring context. And about exception handling: The default handling is good already, as long you have defined a backout threshold > 0 and backout queue in the queue definition on the queue manager. If you want to do your own exception handling, see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40671764/638413).

Comment: In my opinion the `Simple` listener is even better in that it uses the MQ call back feature, so is not polling the queue even every 30 seconds, it would just stay connected and be called as soon as a message was available.

Comment: @JoshMc Spring boot uses the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which uses `MQGET` and not `MQCB`, as Mark Taylor explained in a comment in your referenced blog post.

Comment: Hi Daniel, that is understood,  but from what I understand you can also configure it to use a [`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html), this with be a normal async message listener using `MQCB`.

Comment: Hi Josh, ok, now I understand what you mean. Yes, you can configure the simple container with [SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory.html).

Comment: @JoshMc what do u suggest ultimately? and if i have to implement using SimpleJmsListener , is it in the configuration class where i have created connection factory , must i implement SimpleJmsListener?

Comment: @JoshMc if i use SimpleJmsListener ...is it not required to add spring.jms.listener.receive-timeout=30s in properties?

Comment: No it is not.  It uses a call back not polling.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> conFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the
        // message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OmnipApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

above is the application configuration class and below is the listener code;

```
@Component
public class MessageReceiverService {

    @Autowired
    MessageValidationService messageValidationService;

    @JmsListener(destination="${inwardQueueName}", containerFactory="conFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(javax.jms.Message message) throws javax.jms.JMSException{
        String messagetxt = "";
        JmsMessageBean bean = new JmsMessageBean();
        if(message!=null){
            bean.setMessage(message.getBody(Object.class));
            bean.setJmsMessageID(message.getJMSMessageID());
        }

        if (bean.getMessage().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("String")) {
            messagetxt = (String) bean.getMessage();
        } else {
            byte[] messagebytes = (byte[]) bean.getMessage();
            messagetxt = new String(messagebytes);
        }
        messagetxt = messagetxt.split(Constants.MESSAGE_END_CHAR)[0].concat(Constants.MESSAGE_END_CHAR);
        messageValidationService.messageIdentifier(messagetxt);
    }

}
```