# Spring Boot JMS Error Handler is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, azureservicebus, spring-jms

I tried implementing Azure Service Bus integration by using Spring Boot and JMS

But error handler is not working as expected, I'm getting a warning

> WARN 10676 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

And sysout is not calling inside the error handler while the exception is thrown. I just tried the below example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49861714Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49861714Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "testMessage");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
             DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
             ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
             ErrorHandler myErrorHandler) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ErrorHandler myErrorHandler() {
        return t -> {
            System.out.println("In error handler");
            t.printStackTrace();
        };
    }
    
    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
}
```

Reference -

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms

[Spring JMS : Set ErrorHandler for @JmsListener annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654586/spring-jms-set-errorhandler-for-jmslistener-annotated-method)

https://lankydan.dev/2017/06/18/using-jms-in-spring-boot

Anyone, please advise on this?

Comment: Have you referred to https://lankydan.dev/2017/06/18/using-jms-in-spring-boot?

Comment: Yes I already referred this link and tried implementing  but same error. No luck @JimXu

Answer (score 1):

You omitted the instruction for Spring to use your customised `org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory` bean . Set this on the  `@JmsListener` annotation using the `containerFactory` property

For example, in your case;

```
@JmsListener(destination = "foo",containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
```