# Separate ErrorHandlers for separate JmsListeners

Tags: spring-jms, spring-messaging

[Here is answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654586/spring-jms-set-errorhandler-for-jmslistener-annotated-method) how to set an `ErrorHandler` for a whole `JmsListenerContainerFactory`.

But I need each JmsListener (`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`) to have its own `ErrorHandler`.

Just having a try-catch inside my listener would not fit, because it won't catch JMS transactions' failures (transaction is committed in Spring, outside of my listener).

I would like to collect such failures by a monitoring system.

I tried to use

```
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry
  .getListenerContainers()
  .forEach{ it.errorHandler = myErrorHandler }
```

But

1. This is a bit tricky.
2. Containers are registered later than `JmsListener`-annotated beans are handled by its BeanPostProcessor. So I struggle with choosing a moment to set error handlers.

Please advise something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to configure separate `JmsListenerContainerFactory` beans for all those different `@JmsListener` and their specific `ErrorHandler`. Each of those `@JmsListener` should refer to their own factory from this option:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible for serving this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```